To enable auto-completion for the data object when converting FormData to an object in TypeScript
When converting FormData to an object in TypeScript, the resulting data does not have auto-completion for its properties.
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Signup() {
  const [passwordAreNotEqual, setPasswordAreNotEqual] = useState(false);

  function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement);
    const acquisitionChannels = formData.getAll('acquisition') as string[];
    const entriesData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

    const data = {
      ...entriesData,
      acquisition: acquisitionChannels,
    };
    console.log(data.password);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2>Welcome on board!</h2>
      <p>We just need a little bit of data from you to get you started </p>

      <div className="control">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required />
      </div>

      <div className="control-row">
        <div className="control">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            id="password"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            required
            minLength={8}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="control">
          <label htmlFor="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
          <input
            id="confirm-password"
            type="password"
            name="confirm-password"
            required
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr />

      <div className="control-row">
        <div className="control">
          <label htmlFor="first-name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" required />
        </div>

        <div className="control">
          <label htmlFor="last-name">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="control">
        <label htmlFor="phone">What best describes your role?</label>
        <select id="role" name="role" required>
          <option value="student">Student</option>
          <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
          <option value="employee">Employee</option>
          <option value="founder">Founder</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>How did you find us?</legend>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="google"
            name="acquisition"
            value="google"
          />
          <label htmlFor="google">Google</label>
        </div>

        <div className="control">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="friend"
            name="acquisition"
            value="friend"
          />
          <label htmlFor="friend">Referred by friend</label>
        </div>

        <div className="control">
          <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="acquisition" value="other" />
          <label htmlFor="other">Other</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <div className="control">
        <label htmlFor="terms-and-conditions">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="terms-and-conditions"
            name="terms"
            required
          />
          I agree to the terms and conditions
        </label>
      </div>

      <p className="form-actions">
        <button type="reset" className="button button-flat">
          Reset
        </button>
        <button type="submit" className="button">
          Sign up
        </button>
      </p>
    </form>
  );
}


in data.password
'{ acquisition: string[]; }' type does not have a 'password' property.ts(2339)
How can I retrieve values from the data object without getting errors?
const data = Object.fromEntries(
      Array.from(formData.entries()).map(([key, value]) => 
        [key, formData.getAll(key).length > 1 ? formData.getAll(key) : value]
      )
    );

 function formDataToObject(formData: FormData): Record<string, string> {
    const obj: Record<string, string> = {};
    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      obj[key] = value as string;
    });
    return obj;
  }

  function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement);
    const acquisitionChannels = formData.getAll('acquisition') as string[];
    const data = {
      ...formDataToObject(formData),
      acquisition: acquisitionChannels,
    };

    if (data.password !== data['confirm-password']) {
      setPasswordAreNotEqual(true);
      return;
    }

    console.log(data);
  }```




const entriesData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()) as Record<string, string>;

I used chatGPT but
Doen't work

